# Get Monthly Delta from Dynamic Date Field in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, powerbi-paginated-reports

Trying to build this report as a paginated report and could not find a way to get the delta between months in a dynamic date range. Want to subtract Apr-March, May-Apr, Jun-May, and so on. How is the monthly delta calculated for cost?

[image]

Comment: [Try the Previous function.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-previous-function?view=sql-server-ver16)